# Drop column in MySqlWorkbench taking a long time

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, alter-table

I started a 'DROP COLUMN' operation in MySQLWorkbench yesterday and it still hasn't finished.  It's now about 16 hours later.  The table only has about 52000 records.

Should I let it run, or should I assume something has gone wrong and stop the process?

Is there any way to know the status of the operation, or if it has hung in some way?

Thanks.

**Update:**

Here are the results from 'desc websvc_userprofile' and 'show processlist'

The processlist seems to indicate that the only processes are coming from my webserver instance, not MySqlWorkbench that is running on my desktop.  Also, the column that I was trying to drop, is not displayed in the results of the 'desc websvc_userprofile' command.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you plz add the output of following commands :
`desc <tablename>`; show indexes from `<tablename>`; I might suspect the column you are deleting would be part of an index created on that table.

Comment: Try run `show processlist` using a new session to that database. My guess is that your table is locked and therefore the `drop` operation hangs.

Comment: I added the output of the two commands above.

Comment: I also added the output from show indexes from websvc_userprofile;  The column that I dropped is not in the list of idexes.